# IE8 can't open any secure (https://) sites

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8

This is weird. I can't even access paypal.com, it simply says "Internet explorer cannot display this webpage", as if it couldn't locate it. Yet, I get to it just fine in chrome.

I have even gone to `Internet settings -> reset` to reset all of my options - no go. I have tried lowering my security settings to the bare minimum. Yes, I have the SSL and TLS options checked under Security. I'm out of ideas. Anyone?

I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: A long shot, but does turning of your firewall (if any) help?

Comment: Can Firefox, Chrome, or Opera access any HTTPS sites?

Comment: Really, you should upgrade to IE11, which is available here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-11-for-windows-7-details.aspx or in Windows Update

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow Microsoft article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968089/en-us

and

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813444

Answer (score 1):

I know it sounds silly, but make sure your Date/Time settings are correct, I have seen this issue caused multiple times simply from a wrong time.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I have found [source: 
[Cannot Access Secure HTTP Sites?](http://www.techsupportall.com/solved-cannot-access-secure-sites-https-websites-not-opening-view/) ]

**1)** Open **START >** and run > **CMD** .  insert & execute this command (or one by one, but remove `&&`):

```
regsvr32 urlmon.dll && regsvr32 wintrust.dll && regsvr32 initpki.dll && regsvr32 dssenh.dll && regsvr32 rsaenh.dll && regsvr32 gpkcsp.dll && regsvr32 sccbase.dll && regsvr32 slbcsp.dll && regsvr32 cryptdlg.dll && regsvr32 shdocvw.dll && regsvr32 mshtml.dll && regsvr32 browseui.dll && regsvr32 jscript.dll && regsvr32 vbscript.dll && regsvr32 oleaut32.dll && regsvr32 softpub.dll && regsvr32 urlmon.dll && regsvr32 actxprxy.dll
```

(p.s. To paste inside CMD, right click> **PASTE**)

**2)** Then open **INTERNET EXPLORER > Tool> Internet Option>** AND

---**a)**  in **Security Tab>** choose **trusted Sites** and then click on **default level**. Then click **SITES** and add there your sites.

---**b)** in **Content** Tab > click on **Clear SSL State**
You will get a message that the SSL cache was cleared Successfully, click on OK

---**c)** in **Advanced** Tab >  check **USE SSL3.0** and **SSL 2.0** (in some cases, before that, you may need click "RESET DEFAULTS+RESET", and do all the above steps again..)

**3)** Check your COMPUTER DATES (year,month,day), it needs to be correct.

p.s. Problems solved:

```
Unable to view & open https secure website, they not opening, nor loading..; Internet Explorer Cannot Connect to Secure Sites; Https Sites Not Working Ie9; Can't  browse or Access Secure(for example Bank) websites; I cannot log in to or connect... these might happen after upgrading.
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page goes is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).

Answer (score 0):

After being badly annoyed by this problem for months, after searching the web and as usual finding everywhere the same advices infinitely repeated and probably never checked since they as usual never worked, I finally found one that, today and in my case (that I may expand if needed), worked immediately:

[Internet Explorer - Unable to access secure websites (HTTPS/SSL)](http://ccm.net/faq/29189-internet-explorer-unable-to-access-secure-websites-https-ssl)

... *(2) Click the Tools menu > "Internet Options." Click the Advanced tab > Security section. Check the boxes for **"Use SSL 2.0**" and "**Use SSL 3.0**".* ...

I personally also checked the "**Use TLS 1.0**" case.

Versailles, Sat 01 Oct 2016 11:39:20 +0200

Answer (score -1):

The key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\fipsalgorithmpolicy

The value should be 0

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what this setting does.